# Magento gives error page instead of product view

Tags: database, magento, structure, apc, permalinks

I have a problem with a Magento webshop (already live -> http://tinyurl.com/bu8vzay).
When you choose a product in a category you will always get an 404 error page.

Do you have any idea?

Things I tried:

- updating attributes for all products live (no problems)
- clear cache
- clearing the indexes

I've been searching for too many hours now. All help is welcome :)

Comment: Take look at the Catalog -> Url Rewrtie Section in admin to see if a rewrite is added for that product.... Also take a look at this table http://expertmagentodevelopers.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/404-error-on-magento-product-page/

Comment: Thank you so much! I think the rewrites made a never-ending loop (which causes the long waiting time).. And doing all the things in your link solves my problem!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take look at the Catalog -> Url Rewrtie Section in admin to see if a rewrite is added for that product.

You may also want to check report_event_types table to see if the values below exist, if not then insert them (Always backup your database before making changes):

```
INSERT INTO `report_event_types` (`event_type_id`, `event_name`, `customer_login`) VALUES
(1, 'catalog_product_view', 1),
(2, 'sendfriend_product', 1),
(3, 'catalog_product_compare_add_product', 1),
(4, 'checkout_cart_add_product', 1),
(5, 'wishlist_add_product', 1),
(6, 'wishlist_share', 1);
```

Credit to [404 Error on Magento Product Page](http://expertmagentodevelopers.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/404-error-on-magento-product-page/)

Comment: I first truncated core_rewrite_url, and after that I did this wich worked!